# creating a dynamic dropdown field in php

Tags: php, html

I want creat a dropdown text field when dneeded by clicking on a button in php or html.

Comment: zomg! I want too!!!  What did you try to do so far?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two choices:

1. Generate the dropdown **on the client** via JavaScript and DOM manipulation (show hidden dropdown, generate via DOM operations using [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) and the like, use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), …)
2. Generate the dropdown **on the server** (reload the page when button is clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ajax to load the dropdown html from your server or you may load it (hidden) with the first loading of your page and make it visible when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a tutorial [here](http://www.tips4design.com/2010/12/jq-create-animated-drop-down-menu.html) that I think is what you were looking for. You can easily customize the jQuery script for your needs.